# postgresql build_json_object returns

Tags: json, postgresql

postgesql returns the json_build_object as a parent for each grouped json array like this:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "stories": [{
        "json_build_object": {
          "CNN": []
        }
      },
      {
        "json_build_object": {
          "FOX": []
        }
      },
      {
        "json_build_object": {
          "Huffpost": []
        }
      },...
```

Postgresql returns the "json_build_object" as a key.
Is it possible to replace with the stories.source value returned by the group by?

```
SELECT json_build_object(source, json_agg(stories.*))
FROM stories
GROUP BY stories.source
ORDER BY source;
```

Optimal solution would be a response like this:

```
 stories:
  CNN: [],
  FOX: []...
```

I'm sure I'm missing a best practice for returning JSON in Postgresql...

Comment: pg-promise doesn't modify data it receives.

Comment: Ok, then how did that json_build_object attribute get added?  I noticed this occurs when using db.func() syntax as well.

Comment: That's what you get from the query. And it is completely outside of pg-promise.

Comment: Thanks for the secondary clarification!  Have updated original post to postgresql specific.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a way to do this in SQL, but for the lack of it now, you can convert that `stories` property into the right object:

```
function convert(stories) {
    const res = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < stories.length; i++) {
        const obj = stories[i].json_build_object;
        const name = Object.keys(obj)[0];
        res[name] = obj[name];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vitaly, this is what I had planned to do with no SQL option found yet.  Will post the solution when I figure it out.

Comment: Anyone figured out that out yet? Ran into the same issue myself.